# github-pages gem failing even though I have Ruby version 2.1.2

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to install github pages gem on my Mac OS X (yosemite).

I get following error:

```
Gem::InstallError: github-pages requires Ruby version ~> 2.0.0.
An error occurred while installing github-pages (4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install github-pages -v '4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I checked my Ruby version by running following command -

```
ruby --version
```

And it says

```
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
```

So I definitely have Ruby version ~> 2.0.0

Any assistance on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There is a possible lack of important information here.  Looking at your Ruby version, are you using rbenv or rvm?

I could imagine this happening if you use rbenv or rvm and then `su` or `sudo` to gem install github-pages.  rbenv and rvm are specific to your user account and your shell environment.  If you `su` or `sudo` to root, rbenv and rvm are no longer active.

The other possibility is that you are running it inside of a Bundler managed app that specifies another Ruby version in the `Gemfile` using the `ruby x.x.x` syntax.

If neither of these is the case, try running `gem env` to see what exactly rubygems thinks the story is.  Also post the exact commands you are using to get this error.